# How to access Flutter Back button functionality?

Tags: function, dart, flutter

I would like to present an AdWords interstitial before the user returns to the previous page. How can I do this when the return button is pressed?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I think you can make use of [`WillPopScope`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html) widget. You can pass a callback function which will be called when the view is about pop. Just do whatever tasks to be completed before pop and then return true.

Example:

```
Future<bool> _willPopCallback() async {
    // await showDialog or Show add banners or whatever
    // then
    return true; // return true if the route to be popped
}


//then pass the callback to WillPopScope
new WillPopScope(child: new Scaffold(), onWillPop: _willPopCallback)
```

Comment: is there any way to keep the swipe to pop functionality when using a WillPopScope? Mine stops working when I add it.

I am trying to use it so that when someone swipes to pop, the keyboard will dismiss, but I have yet to figure it out. I tried it with a Pan Gesture but that works on swipe everywhere but the edge where swipe to pop happens.

Comment: The argument type 'Future<bool>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<bool> Function()'.

Comment: I think you are making a function call `_willPopCallback()`, just use `_willPopCallback`