# I want new (fresh) flutter page widget every time I open it

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget, flutter-android

When I leave a page widget and come back to it later, it retains the previous info on the previous session. I would like to create a fresh page widget from scratch every time I opened it. How do I implement this?

Comment: You can pop navigation twice `Navigator.pop(context)` and then navigate to your screen again, you will find it as a fresh one absolutely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the main data of the widget in the widget declaration works. I suppose the problem was the scope of the data used. If outside the widget declaration, the data would basically be global and would be the same every time the widget is navigated to.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that your issue is the after going to new page using Navigator.push(), you get the previous state of the page after popping the new page.

In that case you can call a setState after popping the new page. Do the following :

Navigator.pop() on Page2 :

```
Navigator.pop(context,1);    /// Passing an extra parameter (1) to Page1 after popping
```

Navigator.push() in Page1 :

```
Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page2())).then((value){
      if(value == 1)
        setState(() {});         /// Here you can keep a conditional refresh like if you pass 1 in Navigator.pop() then only will it refresh the page
/// It's useful when you want to refresh the page only for specific conditions.
});
```

The .then() function after Navigator.push() will be called after Page2 is popped and as mentioned in that function, a setState() will be called refreshing the page.

Comment: Page2 uses the automatic back button

Comment: The you can override the back button to control what it will do on tapped. Follow this  link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49079580/how-to-access-flutter-back-button-functionality

Comment: That wasn't clear. One could use this though:
```appBar: AppBar(
        leading: BackButton(onPressed: () {
          
        },),
```

Comment: I thought you were talking about the android/ios device back button

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that when you are navigating through the pages you close them properly (end their life circle). If not try to navigate with Are you sure that when you are navigating through the pages you close them properly (end their life circle). If not try to navigate with `pushReplacement` instead of `push`